# How to store WebsocketSession in redis cache?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce, reddison

How to Store websocket session in redis java Redis Client .please give some example.

Comment: Why would you persist websocket sessions to redis cache? As long as the connection is open, the Java server needs to be aware of them, so it will have them in memory. When the connections are closed, they are no longer valid and a new session needs to be created.

Comment: It Require for Maintaining consistency during deployment or other failure .. is it possible to store websocket session in cache .. any examples